# How to print certain range of value in array after sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have been working on this program for days now and still having these difficulties.

I need to make a program that can sort with Bubble sort, Selection Sort, Insertion Sort, and Shell Sort.
It has to read from a .bin file also print how long it took to sort the numbers.
The current program is sorting and giving me the run time.

Currently, the problem is: I need to create lower and upper bound of that array:
So after picking a sort, the user should see the start time, then a pause while the sort happens, then the end time should print, then they should be prompted for the lower and upper bounds, then that range of numbers should be printed out.

I was told that this program looks more like a C. I haven't really ever been working with C++ and I'm still learning this language. Any input and help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
void timing() {
 timeb timebuffer;
//char timeline[26];
time_t timeline;

ftime(&timebuffer);
ctime(&timeline);

printf("The time is %.19s.%hu %s", timeline, timebuffer.millitm, &timeline);

system("pause");}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], const int size){

for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
{
    bool swapped{ false };

    for (int y = 0; y < size - 1; ++y)
    {
        if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1])
        {
            swap(arr[y], arr[y + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
        if (arr[y] < arr[y + 1])
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (!swapped)
    {
        cout << "Early termination on iteration: " << x + 1 << "\n";
    }
}}


void selectionSort(int arr[], int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j <size; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < arr[i])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}}
```

//insertion sort

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int size) {
for (int i = 1; 1 < size; i++) {
    int j = arr[i];
    j= i-1;
    while (j >= 0 && arr[j - 1] > j)
    {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    arr[j + 1] = j;
}}
```

//shellsort

```
void shellSort(int arr[], int size){
int RE;
 for (int Ns = size / 2; Ns >= 1; Ns /= 2) {
    for (int Head = Ns + 1; size;) {
        arr[Head]=arr[0];//
        RE = Head - Ns;
    }
    while (RE>=0 && arr[0] < RE) {
        arr[RE]=arr[RE + Ns];
        RE = RE - Ns; //break out of loop when(-)
    }
}}
```

//print array after sort

```
void printArray(int *arr, int size) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}}
```

//the main code

```
int main(){
    int choice;
    clock_t startTime, endTime; //for calculating time
    double totalTime; //calculating total time
    int* arr;
    char fileName[50];
    int readVal;
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    //read data from file.bin
    cout << "Enter a filename to sort => ";
    cin >> fileName;

    FILE* inFile;

    inFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fread(&size, sizeof(size), 1, inFile);
    arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fread(&readVal, sizeof(readVal), 1, inFile);
        arr[i] = readVal;
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    //ask user which type of sorting they want to use
    cout << "Please make the following selection:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Bubble Sort:" << endl;
    cout << "2. Selection Sort: " << endl;
    cout << "3. Insertion Sort: " << endl;
    cout << "4. Shell Sort: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    //choice of sorting method
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: cout << "You have chosen Bubble Sort:" << endl;
        startTime = clock();
        bubbleSort(arr, size);
        printf("Sorted array: \n");
        printArray(arr, size);
        printf("\nStart Time: \n");
        endTime = clock();
        printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
        totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
        printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
        printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
        break;
    case 2: cout << "You have chosen Selection Sort:" << endl;
        startTime = clock();
        selectionSort(arr, size);
        printf("Sorted array: \n");
        printArray(arr, size);
        printf("\nStart Time: \n");
        endTime = clock();
        printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
        totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
        printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
        printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
        break;
    case 3: cout << "You have Chosen Insertion Sort:" << endl;
        startTime = clock();
        insertionSort(arr, size);
        printf("Sorted array: \n");
        printArray(arr, size);
        printf("\nStart Time: \n");
        endTime = clock();
        printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
        totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
        printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
        printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
        break;
    case 4: cout << "You have Chosen Shell Sort: " << endl;
        startTime = clock();
        shellSort(arr, size);
        printf("Sorted array: \n");
        printArray(arr, size);
        printf("\nStart Time: \n");
        endTime = clock();
        printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
        totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
        printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
        printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also in case 1: I use  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }  To see if my printArray was giving me a problem. It seems to give me the same unsorted number

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. If you store the lower bound in `low` and the upper bound in `high`, you could easily call your function `printArray` like this: `printArray(&arr[low], high - low + 1)`. That's assuming your user enters zero-based bounds and you have checked that they are valid.

You're right that this looks like C, it's because it follows an imperative style of programming. A C++ program normally follows the object-oriented paradigm where everything is represented as classes and objects. It's a bit tricky to find the objects here because it's rather abstract. As an example, you could have a UI object to handle user input and you could represent the algorithms as classes too. Have a look at the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It's probably too advanced at this stage but it might help you see how you could represent algorithms as classes.

There's a lot of repetition in your case handling, you might want to refactor that by extracting the parts that differ (the name of the algorithm and of course the function) and feeding them to a single function. The name and the function could be bundled in an object and you could have an array of those that you can plug into your UI handling.

One last thing: I'd advise to call `clock()` right after the sort function, keep the calls to `printf` out of it. I/O is slow and might skew your results.

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few errors in you code. A few off by one errors. One thing to note is that arr is not an array but a pointer. And so size will be incorrectly calculated. Fix is below.

```
int main(){
int choice;
clock_t startTime, endTime; //for calculating time
double totalTime; //calculating total time
int arr[1000]; //allocate 1 thousand ints to be sorted
char fileName[50];
int readVal;
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

//read data from file.bin
cout << "Enter a filename to sort => ";
cin >> fileName;

FILE* inFile;

inFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    fread(&readVal, sizeof(readVal), 1, inFile);
    arr[i] = readVal;
}

fclose(inFile);

//ask user which type of sorting they want to use
cout << "Please make the following selection:" << endl;
cout << "1. Bubble Sort:" << endl;
cout << "2. Selection Sort: " << endl;
cout << "3. Insertion Sort: " << endl;
cout << "4. Shell Sort: " << endl;
cin >> choice;

//choice of sorting method
switch (choice) {
case 1: cout << "You have chosen Bubble Sort:" << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    bubbleSort(arr, size);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
    totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
    printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
    printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
    break;
case 2: cout << "You have chosen Selection Sort:" << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    selectionSort(arr, size);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    endTime = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
    totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
    printArray(arr, size);
    printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
    printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
    break;
case 3: cout << "You have Chosen Insertion Sort:" << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    insertionSort(arr, size);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    endTime = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
    totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
    printArray(arr, size);
    printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
    printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
    break;
case 4: cout << "You have Chosen Shell Sort: " << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    shellSort(arr, size);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    endTime = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (float)endTime);
    totalTime = ((double)(endTime - startTime));
    printArray(arr, size);
    printf("\n\nendtime : %f\n", (float)endTime);
    printf("\n\ntotal time of execution = %f", totalTime);
}
return 0;}
```

You may want to calculate the size from the number of lines in the file, this uses a fixed size of 1 thousand items.

Comment: OP\s code does read the size from the file and allocates based on that.

Comment: And what are you basing that on? Pure guesswork? What's certain is that your answer will use an incorrect size as you hardcoded it, which is obviously wrong.